# InvalidArgumentError: Incompatible shapes: [3] vs. [4]

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to use the `tf.data` API for the first time [with help from this example](https://github.com/tensorflow/compression/blob/master/examples/bmshj2018.py), I have 3D volume data, i.e instead of (height, width, channel), I have (depth, height, width, channel).

```
def readfile(filenames):
    name = filenames[0]
    string = tf.read_file(name)
    image = tf.image.decode_image(string, channels=3)
    bunch = image
    for name in filenames[1:]:
        string = tf.read_file(name)
        image = tf.image.decode_image(string, channels=3)
        bunch = tf.concat([bunch,image],1)   
    return bunch

with tf.device("/cpu:0"):

    #read data file paths, shape [5,100] (five elements each with 100 frames)
    train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(train_files) 
    #train_dataset.element_spec gives shape=(100,)
    train_dataset = train_dataset.map(readfile, num_parallel_calls=16)
    #readfile function takes element of shape (1,100) and 
    #reads each frame and appends to a tensor which is returned 
    #train_dataset.element_spec gives shape=<unknown>
    train_dataset = train_dataset.map(lambda x: tf.random_crop(x, (100, 256, 256, 3)))
    #train_dataset.element_spec gives shape=(100, 256, 256, 3)
    train_dataset = train_dataset.batch(1)

    x = train_dataset.make_one_shot_iterator().get_next()
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/anaconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/client/session.py", line 1365, in _do_call
return fn(*args)
  File "/anaconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/client/session.py", line 1350, in _run_fn
target_list, run_metadata)
  File "/anaconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/client/session.py", line 1443, in _call_tf_sessionrun
run_metadata)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: {{function_node __inference_Dataset_map_<lambda>_258}} Incompatible shapes: [3] vs. [4]
 [[{{node random_crop/GreaterEqual}}]]
 [[IteratorGetNext]]
```

I can't understand the error. I think it means the `tf.random_crop` is giving a 3D tensor shape while `.get_next()` part is giving a 4D tensor? I have doubt with the shape of `train_dataset` after `readfile` function is applied, why is the shape `<unknown>`, I would expect something like (?,100,256,256,3). Where am I going wrong?

Is there a way to visualise the frames in train_dataset so I know I'm doing it right? I have always used `feed_dict` and there it's easy to visualise the numpy frames so I know exactly what I'm feeding.

Comment: can you post readfile function ? also, make it accept element of shape (100,) instead of (1,100). My guess is it  is not reading any data at all if you have not reshaped the tensors to (100,1) inside the function

Comment: @MiloMinderbinder I have updated with readfile function code. It seems the input to this function is single dimension, which is why I wrote it this way. When I tried some other variations it gave me error `ValueError: Index out of range using input dim 1; input has only 1 dims for 'strided_slice' (op: 'StridedSlice') with input shapes: [100], [2], [2], [2] and with computed input tensors: input[3] = <1 1>.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based upon the limited information i see both fundamental and technical errors in your code:

I assume you have (equivalent of) 5 directories with 100 frames. You have a tensor train_dataset with 5 rows and 100 columns with each element being a directory and each value in the element being a path

Fundamental:

1. This isnt an error but i lapse of understanding. When you run `train_dataset = train_dataset.map(readfile, num_parallel_calls=16)` you are actually sending in tensors of shape (100,) instead of (1,100) that you thought but, your function is written right and is handling (100,) the right way
2. Inside readfile you are doing `bunch = tf.concat([bunch,image],1)`. This will concatenate your images along dimension 1. If your images are (100,100,3) then you are creating (100,100*100,3) as the output of readfile. So, you are effectively getting (5,100,100*100,3) as the return value of `train_dataset.map(readfile, num_parallel_calls=16)`. Maybe you want to use stack here. Also, 'MapDataset' object has no attribute 'elem_spec' so how you are getting unknown as the output of elem_spec of train_dataset beats me

Technical:

1. Now,this is the line your code is breaking at `train_dataset = train_dataset.map(lambda x: tf.random_crop(x, (100, 256, 256, 3)))`. `x` is shaped (5,100,100*100,3) so each element that random_crop is taking is (100,100*100,3) and you cannot crop it to (100,256,256,3). This is how cropping is used effectively

```
image = tf.image.random_crop(image, size=[28, 28, 1]) # Random crop back to 28x28
```

Here image is a batch of images of shape (34,34,1)

All things considered i think Your issue is generating from using `tf.concat` where you wanted to use [`tf.stack`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/stack)

Comment: so I understood the mistake, although what worked for me was to use 'tf.expand_dims' and 'tf.concat'. Thanks!

Comment: tf.expand_dims followed by tf.concat is tf.stack only